# How to avoid "session not created exception" in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with selenium but it seems that chrome browser update broke my testing environment and capybara tests are throwing the next:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.evaluate missing 'wasThrown'
```

I'm using:

```
gem 'rspec',               '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'capybara',            '~> 2.4.4'
gem 'selenium-webdriver',  '~> 2.47.1'
gem 'chromedriver-helper', '~> 1.0.0'
```

The situation here is that chromedriver-helper latest release is the one I have, so I suppose I need to update chromedriver but gem install it automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just reviewed the gem documentation in github.com:

https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper

And I found the next to update chromedriver automatically:

> If you'd like to force-upgrade to the latest version of chromedriver,
>   run the script **chromedriver-update** that also comes packaged with this
>   gem.

So just apply:

```
$ chromedriver-update
```